# Debezium: Check if snapshot is complete for postgres initial_only

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using Debezium postgres connector v1.4.2.Final.

I'm using `snapshot.mode=initial_only`, where I only want to get the table(s) snapshot and not stream the incremental changes. Once the snapshot is completed, I want to stop/kill the connector. How can I find out if the snapshotting is complete and that it's safe to kill the connector?

I'm using this to be able to add new tables to an existing connector. For doing that I'm trying this:

1. kill the original connector (`snapshot.mode=initial`)
2. start a new connector with `snapshot.mode=initial_only` for new tables
3. stop the new connector once snapshotting is complete
4. Start original connector after adding new tables to table.whitelist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check JMX metrics. Verify if this one https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.5/connectors/postgresql.html#connectors-snaps-metric-snapshotcompleted_postgresql would suite to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Jiri. One question - if it's a cluster setup, will only the pod running the particular connector return this metric? In that case do I first need to find out which pod/node is running the connector in question?

Comment: Yes, only one node reads the connector and only one thus exposes the metircs. But if you use Prometheus than you can use JMX exporter and get the metrics into central place so you don't need to locate precise node.

Comment: Yes, I decided to go that way - using Prometheus. But feels kinda strange, using something like Prometheus for inter process communication. Anyways, thanks for the help Jiri